# Changing from parameter to variable in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction

I'm having trouble defining a function where I previously treated a variable as a parameter.  See the following example:

```
var := 2*a
f[a_] := var
```

Then `f[a]` returns `2a` but `f[2]` only returns `f[2]` without evaluation.  I understand I could just define `var` as a function of `a` but this is unwieldy for the number of parameters I am using. Is there a function that will 'dereference' `var`?

Comment: closely related: [Enforcing correct variable bindings](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478), [11461](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11461/5478)

Comment: even closer: [69590](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/5478)

Comment: [91319](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91319/5478), [42691](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42691/5478)

Comment: Is this your goal at the end? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14310/5478

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but you should be aware that, given your definitions, the argument of `f` has no effect on the value of `f` when `f[...]` is evaluated. Only the value of `a` in the current scope of `f` matters.

```
var := 2 a
f[a_] := var

Clear[a]; x = 0; f[x]
```

> `2 a`

```
a = 42; x = 0; f[x]
```

> `84`

You may as well write

```
f := var
```

or forget `f` altogether.

P.S. Mathematica's scoping rules not at all much like those of C or Java.

Answer (score 2):

1. From your description it looks like you included an underscore in your definition above that you left out when testing.
2. I suppose what you are looking for is `f[a_] := Evaluate[var]`
3. This is a horrific design and will sooner or later produce problems.  Good luck.